# How to count blanks in a row, after first Non Blank cell of that Row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

For instance i have a **range "B3:AY3"** and first **non blank cell that contains value is "R3"**, i need to **count all blank cells after cell "R3"**

Comment: Whats the difference between after the first or just count all subtract 1, to account for the first? `=Countif(B3:AY3, "")-1`

Comment: well there is difference mate, because range "B3:AY3" have a non continuous data, so as i wrote the first non blank cell is "R3" in this range & there is data available after "R3" as well, I need to count the blank cells after "R3"... and there are 74000 rows almost with different cells that contains First Value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula must be **array-entered**:

A3:    =COUNTBLANK(OFFSET(MyRange,0,MATCH(
    TRUE,LEN(MyRange)>0,0)-1,1,COLUMNS(
    MyRange)-MATCH(TRUE,LEN(MyRange)>0,0)+1))

where MyRange = B3:AY3

and fill down as needed

---

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
**ctrl-shift** while hitting **enter**.  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces {...} around the formula.

The above formula will return an error message if there are ONLY blank cells in the range, or if there are any cells in the range which contain an error.  If that is a problem, use the following **array-entered** formula instead:

```
=IFERROR(COUNTBLANK(OFFSET(MyRange,0,MATCH(
TRUE,IFERROR(LEN(MyRange)>0,TRUE),0)-1,1,COLUMNS(
MyRange)-MATCH(TRUE,IFERROR(LEN(MyRange)>0,TRUE),0)+1)),COLUMNS(MyRange))
```

IT will count errors as being non-blanks, and count all the cells if all are blank.

Comment: You could use the same formula but change your `Match` function and then your formula would no longer be Array. You could use the following `=COUNTBLANK(OFFSET(MyRange,0,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((Values<>0),0),0)-1,1,COLUMNS( MyRange)-MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((Values<>0),0),0)+1))`

Answer (score 0):

> and first non blank cell that contains value is "R3"

I have taken the example for Row 1. Amend as applicable :)

Try This

`=COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(TRUE,LEN(A1:AY1)=0,0)) & ":AY1"))`

Enter this as an Array Formula. i.e you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

For 3rd row, the formula becomes

`=COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,MATCH(TRUE,LEN(A3:AY3)=0,0)) & ":AY3"))`

[image]

Comment: Sorry it doesn't seems to be working, as it's returning "70" as an answer where total no of cells available in the range "B3:AY3" are "50"

Comment: what formula did you use?

Comment: {=COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(TRUE,LEN(B3:AY3)=0,0)) & ":AY3"))}

Comment: You didn't change `ADDRESS(1` to `ADDRESS(3` :) That is the row number

Comment: @TusharVarshney: Was my solution too difficult to understand?

Comment: Can you see the screenshot in my answer?

Comment: i am sorry i m not sure how paste the screenshot, but the formula above given by Ron worked...

Comment: you need to upload it in wikisend.com and share the link here

Comment: why not change it to `=COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),MATCH(TRUE,LEN(A3:AY3)=0,0)) & ":AY3"))` and then you wouldn't have to change the fomrula but simply drag down?

Comment: @user2140261: Yup we can do that in case the formula needs to be dragged down :)

Comment: ACtual you can do as i recomended to ron also, and replace your `Match` function so, if you use `=COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((Values<>0),0),0)+1)&":AY"&ROW()))` you wouldn't need to modify it per row, or array enter it

Comment: @user2140261: I would recommend putting it an answer if it works (Can't test it now) a normal formula is any day better than an array formula :)

Comment: Just did, think i got a pretty simple answer that works, and doesn't use array enter or any volatile functions either.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need it to work for row three then use the following:

```
=COUNTBLANK(B3:AY3) - (MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((B3:AY3<>0),0),0)-1)
```

This is a regular formula and will not need to be entered as an array, also as I am not using any Volatile function (like INDIRECT and OFFSET) in should also be much better performance wise.

All I m doing is counting all blanks, then subtracting all the blanks before the first cell with a value.